# hook_comment not modifying data

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-comments

I want to change the name of the comment from the users account name to use the real name of the user (I am using RealName and CCK fields).

This should be simple, however it is not correctly saving my values.

```
function mymodule_comment(&$a1, $op) {
    switch ($op) {
        case 'insert':
        case 'update':
            $realname = realname_get_user($a1['uid']);

            if ($realname) {
                $a1['name'] = $realname->name;
            }

            break;
        case 'view':
            $realname = realname_get_user($a1->uid);

            if ($realname) {
                $a1->name = $realname->name;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

If I dump a1 in both cases, the name is what I want it to be. This is not what is saved to the database, however.

How can I change the values so they are actually inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide info about realname_get_user function or else you can try below snippet

```
function mymodule_comment(&$a1, $op) {
    global $user;
    switch ($op) {
        case 'insert':
        case 'update':
            $realname = $user->name;

            if ($realname) {
                $a1['name'] = $realname;
            }

            break;
        case 'view':
            $realname = $user->name;

            if ($realname) {
                $a1->name = $realname;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code appropriately, click on the [orange question-mark](http://i.imgur.com/GjKAG.png) in the question or answer text box for help. Thanks!